# Hide/Close PickerView after value is selected

Tags: ios, swift

I am not using the default UIPickerView, please don't mark this as duplicate.

I am using this library to easily create forms: https://github.com/ortuman/SwiftForms

I want to hide the pickerview once the user has selected a value. I tried:
`pickerView.hidden = true` but I still get a gray bar below the form:
[image]

Here is the custom control:

```
//
//  FormPickerCell.swift
//  SwiftForms
//
//  Created by Miguel Angel Ortuno on 22/08/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Miguel Angel Ortuño. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

public class FormPickerCell: FormValueCell, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    // MARK: Properties

    private let picker = UIPickerView()
    private let hiddenTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectZero)

    // MARK: FormBaseCell

    public override func configure() {
        super.configure()
        accessoryType = .None

        picker.delegate = self
        picker.dataSource = self
        hiddenTextField.inputView = picker

        contentView.addSubview(hiddenTextField)
    }

    public override func update() {
        super.update()

        picker.reloadAllComponents()
        titleLabel.text = rowDescriptor.title

        if let value = rowDescriptor.value {
            valueLabel.text = rowDescriptor.titleForOptionValue(value)
            if let options = rowDescriptor.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.Options] as? NSArray {
                let index = options.indexOfObject(value)
                if index != NSNotFound {
                    picker.selectRow(index, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public override class func formViewController(formViewController: FormViewController, didSelectRow selectedRow: FormBaseCell) {

        if selectedRow.rowDescriptor.value == nil {
            if let row = selectedRow as? FormPickerCell {
                let options = selectedRow.rowDescriptor.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.Options] as? NSArray
                let optionValue = options?[0] as? NSObject
                selectedRow.rowDescriptor.value = optionValue
                row.valueLabel.text = selectedRow.rowDescriptor.titleForOptionValue(optionValue!)
                row.hiddenTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        } else {
            if let row = selectedRow as? FormPickerCell {
                guard let optionValue = selectedRow.rowDescriptor.value else { return }
                row.valueLabel.text = selectedRow.rowDescriptor.titleForOptionValue(optionValue)
                row.hiddenTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: UIPickerViewDelegate

    public func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return rowDescriptor.titleForOptionAtIndex(row)
    }

    public func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        let options = rowDescriptor.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.Options] as? NSArray
        let optionValue = options?[row] as? NSObject
        rowDescriptor.value = optionValue
        valueLabel.text = rowDescriptor.titleForOptionValue(optionValue!)
        pickerView.endEditing(true)
        pickerView.hidden = true
    }

    // MARK: UIPickerViewDataSource

    public func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    public func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if let options = rowDescriptor.configuration[FormRowDescriptor.Configuration.Options] as? NSArray {
            return options.count
        }
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your question is specific to the custom picker you're using. You're unlikely to find anybody here who knows it. I suggest (a) putting the name of the picker control in the title of your post. and (b) posting a question to the author of the control.

Comment: Try `self.view.endEditing(true)`